# How to read multiple words in linux bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I am prompting the user to enter two words separated by space. 
I am using `read name` to read name and then `read last` to read last word 
the user inputs like `name last` separated by space. But read seems to be reading the
whole line. How can I read the first words and the second word separately?

Comment: See the beginning of [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/209184/108618).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you can read into an array.

```
$ read -ra arr
sadf / asdf \ wer
tomasz@fuji:~$ printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}"
sadf
/
asdf
\
wer
```

Each line in this printf output corresponds to a single array item.